# Ruby on Rails App works in development, build succeeds then crashes on Heroku at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-7

Trying to update from Ruby 2.7.6 to Ruby 3.1.2 and Rails 7 - app works in my IDE, build succeeds on Heroku but crashes immediately. I don't see any definitive clue in the logs as to what the issue is. Does anyone know why this is crashing?

```
State changed from crashed to starting
2022-12-08T05:23:42.542074+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2022-12-08T05:23:45.369267+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2022-12-08T05:23:45.369287+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.4 application starting in production
2022-12-08T05:23:45.369287+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2022-12-08T05:23:46.315946+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316211+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.4/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>': Couldn't find Active Storage configuration in /app/config/storage.yml (RuntimeError)
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316219+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `class_eval'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316221+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `block in execute_hook'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316228+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:85:in `with_execution_control'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316229+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:90:in `execute_hook'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316236+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:76:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316238+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:75:in `each'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316245+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:75:in `run_load_hooks'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316247+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.4/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:410:in `<top (required)>'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316254+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316256+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316258+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `const_get'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316274+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `cget'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316274+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:176:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316274+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:40:in `block in ls'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316274+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316276+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316284+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:164:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316285+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316292+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316294+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316300+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316302+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316309+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:296:in `block in eager_load_all'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316310+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `each'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316317+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `eager_load_all'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316318+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:74:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316325+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316327+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316334+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316335+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316342+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316343+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316350+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316352+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316354+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316361+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316363+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316369+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316371+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316378+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316379+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316386+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316387+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316394+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316396+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316403+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316404+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316412+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316413+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316420+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316421+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316428+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316430+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316437+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316438+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316445+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316447+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316454+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316455+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316463+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316464+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316471+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316472+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316480+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316481+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.316488+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2022-12-08T05:23:46.462635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-12-08T05:23:46.515290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-12-08T05:26:30.527592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=workshopcrm.herokuapp.com request_id=7c18154f-cca4-422c-a810-88b145cd6514 fwd="73.145.247.185" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-08T05:30:46.754465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=workshopcrm.herokuapp.com request_id=b0e7114b-3948-42f4-a098-e00043a5c2c6 fwd="73.145.247.185" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my update gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
#gem 'rails', '5.0.7.2'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.0'
#ruby "2.6.4"
#ruby '2.7.6'
#ruby '3.0.4'
ruby '3.1.2'


# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'devise'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
#gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sassc'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'carrierwave', '1.3.1'
gem 'mini_magick', '4.9.3'
#gem 'fog-aws'
#gem 'fog'
gem 'fog-aws', group: :production
#gem 'ransack', '2.1.1'
gem 'ransack', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc

#gem 'bundler', '~> 1.17', '>= 1.17.2'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'sendgrid-ruby'

#gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.2'

#gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.4'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
#gem 'json', '~> 2.6', '>= 2.6.3'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  #gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  #gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 4.2'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  #gem 'pg'
  #changing this to see if I can fix the heroku error
  #gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

This is my update gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activestorage (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    actionmailer (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      actionview (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (7.0.4)
      actionview (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activestorage (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      globalid (>= 0.6.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
    activerecord (7.0.4)
      activemodel (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
    activestorage (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (7.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.18)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.9.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    carrierwave (1.3.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    coffee-rails (5.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
    crass (1.0.6)
    devise (4.8.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-bootstrap-views (1.1.0)
    erubi (1.11.0)
    excon (0.94.0)
    execjs (2.8.1)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    fog-aws (3.15.0)
      fog-core (~> 2.1)
      fog-json (~> 1.1)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
    fog-core (2.3.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.71)
      formatador (>= 0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types
    fog-json (1.2.0)
      fog-core
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-xml (0.1.4)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0)
    formatador (1.1.0)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    i18n (1.12.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.5.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    less (2.6.0)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
    less-rails (4.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 4)
      less (~> 2.6.0)
      sprockets (>= 2)
    loofah (2.19.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.8.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    marcel (1.0.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (3.4.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2022.0105)
    mini_magick (4.9.3)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.8.0)
    minitest (5.16.3)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    net-imap (0.3.1)
      net-protocol
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.0)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.3)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.13.10)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.8.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (1.4.5)
    psych (5.0.1)
      stringio
    puma (6.0.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.1)
    rack (2.2.4)
    rack-test (2.0.2)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (7.0.4)
      actioncable (= 7.0.4)
      actionmailbox (= 7.0.4)
      actionmailer (= 7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      actiontext (= 7.0.4)
      actionview (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activemodel (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activestorage (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.0.4)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.5)
    rake (13.0.6)
    ransack (3.2.1)
      activerecord (>= 6.1.5)
      activesupport (>= 6.1.5)
      i18n
    rdoc (6.5.0)
      psych (>= 4.0.0)
    responders (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    ruby_http_client (3.5.5)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sdoc (2.4.0)
      rdoc (>= 5.0)
    sendgrid-ruby (6.6.2)
      ruby_http_client (~> 3.4)
    spring (4.1.0)
    sprockets (4.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stringio (3.0.2)
    thor (1.2.1)
    timeout (0.3.1)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (5.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0, < 8.0)
      execjs (~> 2.7)
      less-rails (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0, < 8.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.2.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    zeitwerk (2.6.6)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootstrap-datepicker-rails
  byebug
  carrierwave (= 1.3.1)
  coffee-rails
  devise
  devise-bootstrap-views
  fog-aws
  jbuilder
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  mini_magick (= 4.9.3)
  pg (~> 1.4, >= 1.4.2)
  puma
  rails (~> 7.0.0)
  rails_12factor
  ransack (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
  sassc
  sdoc
  sendgrid-ruby
  spring
  sprockets-rails
  twitter-bootstrap-rails
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 4.2)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.2p20

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.26
```

I've got the stack updated to Heroku-22 but the app crashes as soon as the build succeeds. Any ideas on what I've got messed up?

Comment: Check the log on line 7:  Couldn't find Active Storage configuration in /app/config/storage.yml (RuntimeError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `config/storage.yml` file, even if you are not explicitly using Active Storage yet, the framework is trying to load the configuration file. Something like this (which is the default) should work:

```yaml
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
# amazon:
#   service: S3
#   access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
#   secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
#   region: us-east-1
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# Remember not to checkin your GCS keyfile to a repository
# google:
#   service: GCS
#   project: your_project
#   credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("path/to/gcs.keyfile") %>
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# mirror:
#   service: Mirror
#   primary: local
#   mirrors: [ amazon, google ]
```

But you can also probably just place there an empty file with a comment:

```
> cat config/storage.yml
# Empty config/storage.yml to avoid Rails crashes on boot
```

Another way to fix it, is to disable the Active Storage engine. To do so, in the `config/application.rb` file, instead of requiring the whole Rails `require "rails/all"`, you can pick the frameworks you want (remove the entries that you don't want to load):

```rb
require "rails"

%w(
  active_record/railtie
  active_storage/engine
  action_controller/railtie
  action_view/railtie
  action_mailer/railtie
  active_job/railtie
  action_cable/engine
  action_mailbox/engine
  action_text/engine
  rails/test_unit/railtie
).each do |railtie|
  begin
    require railtie
  rescue LoadError
  end
end
```